# How to fix Operand error for method and int

Tags: python-3.x

I have this simple script but i get an operand error in Line 16

Code:

```
class Person:
    number_of_people = 0
    Gravity = -9.5

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        Person.add_person()

    @classmethod
    def number_of_people(cls):
        return cls.number_of_people


    @classmethod
    def add_person(cls):
        cls.number_of_people += 1


p1 = Person("joe")
p2 = Person("frank")

print(Person.number_of_peple())
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app4.py", line 19, in <module>
    p1 = Person("joe")
  File "app4.py", line 7, in __init__
    Person.add_person()
  File "app4.py", line 16, in add_person
    cls.number_of_people += 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'method' and 'int'
```

What can i do to fix this error?

In this question it say i need to take the varaible name but I only want to increment and not have a variable for that

[TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'method' and 'int' (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126072/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-method-and-int-python)

Comment: You have a class variable `number_of_people = 0` and method `def number_of_people(cls):` with the same name. Are you attempting to use a property here?

Comment: methods and variables are both just attributes of a class. as such that means that class attribute names must be unique i.e you cannot have a method and a variable with the same name